# Query in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have 2 SQL Server databases with same structure, first one in SQL Server 2008 and the other in SQL Server 2000.

I wrote a query in SQL Server 2008 like this :

```
SELECT
    sph.SiProforma, SuProforma, cps.Tp_FamilyOffice_Name,
    DsProforma, NaProformaFee, NqCount, 
    NaProformaFee * NqCount as jameradif,
    SUM(NaProformaFee * NqCount) OVER (PARTITION BY suProforma) AS ghabelepardakht
```

and it works in SQL Server 2008, but when I run it in SQL Server 2000 I get this error :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

How can I fix it? Or replace code ?

Comment: where is your `from` clause?

Comment: @Elham sh,It support only from SQL server 2005 on wards. Check below link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Over+Clause/132079/?utm_source=SSC&utm_medium=pubemail

Comment: select  
sph.SiProforma,SuProforma,
cps.Tp_FamilyOffice_Name,DsProforma,NaProformaFee,NqCount,NaProformaFee*NqCount as jameradif,SUM(NaProformaFee*NqCount)
 OVER(PARTITION BY suProforma) AS ghabelepardakht,ssv.Tp_Code_Desc ,
DsContract,proj.TpProject,Status.Tp_Code_Desc,spd.SiGoods,CtbGdsSpc2.TpGds,ctbgdsspc2.CuGds,Ds_Edit,ctbservice.TpService
from Sls.SlsProformaHeader sph left outer join dbo.Ctb_Persons_Specifications cps
on sph.SiPerson=cps.Si_Person left outer join sls.SlsProformaDetail spd 
on sph.SiProforma=spd.SiProforma

Comment: @Mansoor ,i got it,i want an alternate code

Comment: @elhamsh,Provide youe sample data and expected output..?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 doesn't support `OVER`. Write a sub query that performs a `SUM(..) GROUP BY suProforma` and join the sub query to the main table on suProforma

I'd have written an example for you using your tables but for 2 reasons: one that, I'm posting from an iPhone 4 and reformatting your query (it's a bit of a mess- you will do yourself more favours keeping your code neater) is very very hard work and 2, it's not obvious where suProforma column is kept in which table

Here is a simpler example you can apply to your query:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    sq1.summed
FROM
    table1 t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sum(a*b) as summed FROM table1 GROUP BY suProforma) sq2 ON T1.suProforma = sq2.suProforma
```

To apply this query to your situation replace table1 with the table that has suProforma and correct the SUM(a*b) with your actual columns. Then add your other joins in

If he columns you are grouping by and summing are in different tables, then you will have to write a query that links the two together and paste that in (surrounded by brackets) in place of table1

For example these two things are the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1

SELECT *
FROM (select * from table1) sq1
```

Get into the habit of looking at any entity in the FROM part of a query as "just a rectangular block of data from which I can select results"

This query will work in both SQL Server 2000 and 2008

Comment: 'sph' is the table that has suproforma, and 'spd' is the table that has sum's column. so your example did't work in my situation

Comment: I've edited my answer slightly, but there's a basic learning point of databases here: in sql, there isn't really a difference between a table (it is a "block of data") and a subquery (it is a "block of data"). If your columns are in different tables, then swap table1 out for a subquery that returns the data you want